# Noticing common public IP address across all devices

Tags: ip, nat

I  have googled *what is my ip address* from my laptop and got **103.92.123.196**. Doing the same from my Raspberry Pi *and* from my phone, I got the same public IP address. Doing a speedtest on all 3 devices, I still got the same IP address. (103.92.123.196)

I talked with my ISP and he said that the IP I'm shown by these services is his router's static IP address. I'm told that the reason for the same public IP address for my devices is because of NAT. But there has to be a unique (be it dynamic/static) public IP address for my devices.

How can I know the public IP addresses of my each of my individual devices?

I **NEED** to know my Raspberry Pi's public IP address to remote access it from my college. Trying noip's DDNS doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you are connecting to the internet via a Modem/Router then your individual devices don't have public IP addresses. The public IP address of your local network is the WAN address of the Modem/Router. Some ISPs offer multiple public IP addresses but you pay a lot more for thet.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. "

Comment: OP maybe  port forward the ports you need for the Pi (assuming you don't use them for anything else) and then anything you access on those ports with your public IP will go through to the Pi. Also, DDNS will obviously not work as it simply maps your public IP to a hostname. It's very useful but won't give you another public IP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your network layout:

```
                        Internet
                    (public network)
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                     +-----+------+
                     |            |
------------------   |   Router   |   -----------------
                     |            |
                     +---+--+--+--+     private network
                         |  |  |
                         |  |  |
         +---------------+  |  +--------------+
         |                  |                 |
         |                  |                 |
  +------+-----+      +-----+----+      +-----+-----+
  |            |      |          |      |           |
  |   Laptop   |      |   R Pi   |      |   Phone   |
  |            |      |          |      |           |
  +------------+      +----------+      +-----------+
```

Each network has its own address space. An address space is a pool of unique addresses, in this case IP addresses. Each device in a network has one address from its pool. There are two networks here:

- Internet - a huge public network
- Your small private network

Public IP isn't some special kind of IP, it's just an IP in the public network - a single IP from the Internet address space. Your laptop, Pi and phone aren't connected to the Internet directly, so they don't get their own IP address in the Internet. They are in the local network and have local IPs from local network's address space.

A router is a device which joins two networks and lets devices inside them communicate with each other. A router is in both networks simultaneously and has an IP address in each of them. So it has both a public IP in the Internet and a private IP in your local network. All communication between public and private networks goes through the router.

Your router uses a technique called NAT to let devices in private network communicate with other devices in the Internet using router's single public IP. I don't want to go into details of how NAT works - you just have to know that it enables bidirectional communication, *but* it has to be initiated by devices in your local network. If your laptop connects to a public IP, that IP can respond to it. But when you try to reach your Pi from outside local network, it won't work - your router doesn't know which local device should be a target of this connection.

If you can access router's configuration, you can set up *port forwarding* - ie. a rule that external connections to a given port should always be routed to given private IP. For example you can forward port 80 to Pi's local IP to expose Pi's port 80 on router's public IP.

Comment: So is there any way I can access my Raspberry Pi from the internet?

Comment: @PrathamPatel Have you read the last paragraph?